# "Leveling up" with menial labor

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

**Question:** Is there a way a user can increase their reputation level by carrying out menial labor operations such as correcting spelling errors or adding footnotes or the like?

**Rationale:** It would be nice if truly non-expert noobs could earn reputation on a site by helping out with this kind of thing, even if it were just to earn enough reputation to upvote/downvote, with a maximum ceiling so you could not use this to gain a reputation greater than say 200 points.

Answer (score 11):

Huh. I worked hard to gain enough rep so that I could correct spelling errors and add footnotes.

Guess ya just never know what'll appeal to some folks...

Comment: Just helping ya out there. oh the irony...

Comment: These days that feels like all I do on SO. Except when I vote to close.

Answer (score 7):

You can earn badges (well [a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) ) for editing, but that privilege only comes at 100 rep for community wiki and 2000 rep for other people's posts. You have to show that you're a responsible member of the community before you're let loose with editing powers. See the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

It's far easier to earn reputation just by answering and (to a certain extent) by asking questions.

Don't be afraid to add an answer to a question that's already got a few existing answers, you may just provide that extra bit of information the OP needs. If you do there's a potential 25 points of rep right there.

Comment: On SO, it takes 750 rep to edit CW posts.

Comment: @mmyers - your info is out of date - check the faq. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Well, so it is. Have an upvote for showing me something new.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a much better time/rep return from asking questions over on SU, so a "non expert noob" can gain rep, AND stop becoming a non-expert, all at the same time! Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I think asking and answering questions is the way.  If you're willing to have a go of it on Saturday or Sunday you can pick up some really easy questions and gets some rep for them without getting '[Skeeted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting idea.  I think that it is in line with the idea of the system trusting those users that participate in a constructive way.  Of course, there is a reason that you need to earn the trust of the system before being allowed to edit (and how could the system tell if you are fixing spelling errors in a constructive way, or vandalizing answers?)